# Trying to get Parse Facebook login in Samsung Tizen Application

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, tizen

I am making an application for Samsung Tizen and am trying to find a way to get Parse Facebook Login working within the App. Facebook does not allow for the sdk to be loaded on the file system, so I have created a work-around using a popup window that is simply a div element and loading its contents from an external web site(our facebook login).

```
$("#FacebookWindow").html('<object data="http://gibrfacebooklogin2.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/">');
```

The following is the script for the web page that is loaded:

```
Parse.initialize("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
    appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.5',// use graph api version 2.5
    channelUrl : 'http://xxxxxxxxx.html'
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.
  if (Parse.User.current() == null) {
      // Call login method
      Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, {
success: function(user) {
if (!user.existed()) {
console.log("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
//window.location.href = "gibrlanding.html";
    console.log(Parse.User.current().getUsername());
$("#FacebookWindow").remove();
} else {
console.log("User logged in through Facebook!");
    console.log(Parse.User.current().getUsername());
$("#FacebookWindow").remove();
//window.location.href = "gibrlanding.html";
}
},
error: function(user, error) {
console.log("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
}
});
  }
  else{
    console.log("hi");
    console.log(Parse.User.current().getUsername());
    $("#FacebookWindow").remove();
  //window.location.href = "gibrlanding.html";//"file:///opt/usr/apps/0hO6k1Xjui/res/wgt/html/GibberMainMenu.html";
  }

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

What I want to do is load the rest of the app once the user is logged in. To do this I must load from the file system, which is not allowed once you load a web page. To get around this I think I need to place the authentication information somewhere and log into Parse with it. The problem with that is that it seems that you have to use the Facebook Utils of parse to do it, which requires a web page.

Does anybody have a solution/work-around for this problem?

Comment: Ok, So I've figured out how to implement the login in a sense. I have to store the rest of the app's files on a server and just access them on the website. This solution is workable but is clunky and can probably be executed in a more elegant manner. Does anybody have any suggestions?